# Create new column bassed on a text list

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list with sports for example:

```
sports = ["basketball", "football", "baseball"]
```

and a dataframe with a one column with some sentences,

```
column_1
df
My favourite sport is football
I love to play basketball
Football is a family of team sports that involve, to varying degrees, kicking a ball to score a goal
```

I would like to read the list in order to create a second column based on whether the column contains these words. See below

```
df                                                    other
My favourite sport is football                        football
I love to play basketball                             basketball
Football is a family of team sports that involve..    football
```

I don't want to use an if statement because my list contains almost 50 different words.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

try this, [`str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html)

```
import re

sports = ["basketball", "football", "baseball"]

extract_ = re.compile("(%s)" % "|".join(sports), re.IGNORECASE)
df['extract'] = df.column_1.str.extract("(%s)" % "|".join(sports))
```

---

```
0    football
1  basketball
2    Football
```

Comment: Hi @Sushanth. Thank you....But I have a last question. I want to make a new column next to the column that I have the sentences. I don't want to overwrite df.column_1. How can I do this? Thank you again.

Comment: Why use extract when its just a simple case of token matching.

Comment: @AkshaySehgal, yes you're correct this is just one way of solving the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use this. This is straight forward and easy to understand -

```
df['other'] = df['column1'].apply(lambda x: list(set(x.lower().split()).intersection(set(sports)))[0])
```

1. This applies a function that first lowers and then splits the
   sentences into words
2. Then it takes an intersection of the set of words in the sentence and the set of words in the sports list.
3. If each sentence can have more than one sport then remove the `[0]`
   at the end to get a list of sports

```
    column1                         other
0   My favourite sport is football  football
1   I love to play basketball       basketball
2   Football is a family of t...    football
```

Comment: This is more performing good than the regex solution !!

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.DataFrame()

df['column_1'] = ['My favourite sport is football', 'I love to play basketball', 'Football is a family of team sports that involve, to varying degrees, kicking a ball to score a goal']

sports = ["basketball", "football", "baseball"]

list_output = []

for i in range(len(df)):
    
    sentence = df['column_1'].iloc[i]
    for s in sports:
        if s.lower() in sentence.lower(): #s.lower is to avoid missing entries because they're upper case. So I'm comparing then all as lower case
            list_output.append(s)
    
df['sport'] = list_output
```

[image]